# How to solve Twitter API Error "Invalid Media"

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm trying to upload a 15 MB video. In the step INIT, the media_id information is successfully returned from the service

In the APPEND step, we use the Chunk structure and successfully pass bytes array with each chunk value of 4mb

In FINALIZE step, we finish the upload process successfully

However, when we check the shipment with STATUS, we get the following error.

{"media_id":1187325998846660609,"media_id_string":"1187325998846660609","media_key":"7_1187325998846660609","size":8795782,"processing_info":{"state":"failed","progress_percent":100,"error":{"code":1,"name":"InvalidMedia","message":"file is invalid"}}}

```
public class InitModel
    {
        public string media_id { get; set; }
        public string media_id_string { get; set; }
        public string expires_after_secs { get; set; }
    }

#region Init
            var client = new RestClient("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
            {
                Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", "accessToken", "accessTokenSecret")
            };
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("command", "INIT");
            request.AddParameter("total_bytes", size);
            request.AddParameter("media_type", "video/mp4");
            request.AddParameter("media_category", "tweet_video");

            IRestResponse<InitModel> response = client.Execute<InitModel>(request);


            #endregion

#region Append
const int chunkSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
using (var filex = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    int bytesRead, chunkID = 0;
    var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    while ((bytesRead = filex.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
    if (bytesRead < chunkSize)
    {
    var lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
    buffer = new byte[bytesRead];
    buffer = lastBuffer;
    }
    try
    {
    var client1 = new RestClient("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
    {
    Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", "accessToken", "accessTokenSecret")
    };
    var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request1.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    request1.AddParameter("command", "APPEND");
    request1.AddParameter("media_id", response.Data.media_id);
    request1.AddFileBytes("media", buffer, "test");
    request1.AddParameter("segment_index", chunkID.ToString());
    IRestResponse response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"[ERROR] {ex.Message}");
    return;
    }
    chunkID++;
    }
}
#endregion

#region Finalize
            var client2 = new RestClient("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
            {
                Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", "accessToken", "accessTokenSecret")
            };
            var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request2.AddParameter("command", "FINALIZE");
            request2.AddParameter("media_id", response.Data.media_id);

            IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
            #endregion
#region Status
var client4 = new RestClient("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
            {
                Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", "accessToken", "accessTokenSecret")
            };
            var request4 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request4.AddParameter("command", "STATUS");
            request4.AddParameter("media_id", response.Data.media_id);

            IRestResponse response4 = client4.Execute(request4);
    #endregion
```

Comment: Can you provide the `c#` code that you've used to upload the video?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche I added code but, can not share auth token information.

Comment: Does this method works without chunks and smaller files? Have you ever made it to work with more than one chunk?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not allocating byte arrays **inside** the loop. `buffer = new byte[bytesRead];` in particular is pointless and should be removed.

Comment: Your code is hard to read since the indentation is not standard (e.g. `var lastBuffer` should be indented).

Comment: Yeah, 167kb a video file I've successfully uploaded videos.

Comment: @mjwills I can upload a 5mb video with the same code

Comment: You might be 'lucky', since you are never entering the `if (bytesRead < chunkSize)` block until the last read of the file. But that isn't safe to do - `Read` **does not** guarantee to read the entire chunk size. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: How **long** is the video (how many seconds)?

Comment: @mjwills 62 second

Comment: By the way, I tried this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876606/restsharp-addfile-using-stream/56369918#56369918 give me new error : {"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"segment size must be \u003C= 5242880."}

Comment: @mjwills no upload at one time in twitter api, so I must use chunk structure

Comment: @mjwills you are right, when changed chunk structure I have successfully upload. Thank you so much

Comment: You are more than welcome.