# C# Rest API File upload

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am trying too upload a file with C# by an API.

The StreamUtils dont work, I am getting error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".

Any idea on how to upload the file?
It is around 100MB.

```
 public void UploadModel(string ProjectId, string filename, Stream fileStream)
        {

            string access_token_string = Read_Json_Values("access_token");
            string webstring = String.Format("https://api.test.com/v2/projects/{0}/revisions", ProjectId);

            var client = new RestClient(webstring);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token_string);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/ifc");
            request.AddHeader("xxx-Params", "{\"callbackUri\": \"https://example.com\", \"filename\": \"mk337.ifc\", \"comment\": \"From Postman\", \"model\": \"21312312312312\"}");
            request.AddFile("file", s => StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s), filename);


            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine("Model is uploaded!");
        }
```

```
internal static class StreamUtils
        {
            private const int STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE = 128 * 1024; // 128KB

            public static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
            { CopyStream(source, target, new byte[STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE]); }

            public static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target, byte[] buffer)
            {
                if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
                if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

                if (buffer == null) buffer = new byte[STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bufferLength = buffer.Length;
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)) > 0)
                    target.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
```

Comment: I can assume this line `request.AddFile("file",s=>StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s), filename);` throws an Exception, but clarification is needed.

Comment: The line request.AddFile("file", s => StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s), filename) is causing the issue because "s => StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s)" is a lambda expression and not a stream. What you have to do is to define a target Stream as expected in the function StreamUtils.CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)

Comment: It looks like your call to `request.AddFile()` does not match any of the method signatures available: [see this link for clarification](https://i.imgur.com/JjM93BZ.png).

Comment: Does this help? It provides answers of how to upload a file using RestSharp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876606/restsharp-addfile-using-stream

Comment: @rekcul Hey, can you provide an sample code?

Comment: @Kickdak please find my answer below. It's not a full working example as I am still not sure about the CopyStream() implementation, but it should give you an impression about how you can enhance your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two issues in your code
...

**1. Lambda expression issue**

The following line causes the lambda expression issue

```
request.AddFile("file", s => StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s), filename);

// This is the function you want to call
void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
```

So the issue is, that

```
s => StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s)
```

is a Lambda expression, where you define s and give s as second Parameter to

```
CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
```

but s is not of type Stream. That's why you get the exception.

**2. request.AddFile needs Parameters**

Assuming you use the RestSharp NuGet package for your REST request (I assume that because the classes look like the once from RestSharp) you should have a look on the different overloads of RestRequest.AddFile():

```
AddFile(string name, string path, string contentType = null);
AddFile(string name, byte[] bytes, string fileName, string contentType = null);
AddFile(string name, Action<Stream> writer, string fileName, long contentLength, string contentType = null);
```

All functions need several parameters. I guess you want to use the second definition which is

```
AddFile(string name, byte[] bytes, string fileName, string contentType = null);
```

So if we compare it with the line in your code

```
request.AddFile("file", s => StreamUtils.CopyStream(fileStream, s), filename);
```

We see that you give following Parameters:

- "file" as the name
- Function call (Lambda expression) for the bytes
- Filename variable for the filename

The first and third parameters look good but second parameter is an issue.

**My suggestions:**

Define a secound stream parameter in your  UploadModel and pass it to the CopyStream function:

```
public void UploadModel(string ProjectId, string filename, Stream sourceStream, Stream targetStream)
{
    // .... your code still here, just want to show the changing lines
    request.AddFile("file", StreamUtils.CopyStream(sourceStream, targetStream), filename);
}
```

And if you still want to call StreamUtils.CopyStream() to get the second parameter for request.AddFile, you have to change the function definition as it currently returns void. So instead of:

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
public static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target, byte[] buffer)
```

you have to change it to

```
public static byte[] CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
public static byte[] CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target, byte[] buffer)
```

which leads us to the changes in the function body itself, as we now have to return a byte[] accordingly to the functions definition (this is just an example and still needs to get the real implementation which I am currently not able to do, just hope that it gives you an impression how to do it):

```
public static byte[] CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target, byte[] buffer)
{
    // -> Define a byte array
    byte[] bytesToReturn;

    // -> Fill the array with data
    // ...

    // -> return the array
    return bytesToReturn;
}
```

With these changes it should work.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can convert your input file to Base64 and then send it.
See also the answers of other professors what they think.